# Is it possible to print exactly what is in printpreview?

Tags: c#, graphics, printing, drawing, print-preview

can I print what is in the print preview dialog? I have this code and it didn't print what is in the print preview dialog. I mean when I use a one whole bond paper (8.5x11), this code prints on the top-leftmost part of the bond paper but that is not what I want to happen. I need to cut the paper to a size of a cheque then shrink the paper tray of the printer to put the exact size of the paper (size of a cheque). Is this possible?

This is my code:

```
Bitmap MemoryImage;
PrintDocument printdoc1 = new PrintDocument();
PrintPreviewDialog previewdlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
Panel pannel = null;

public chequeLayout()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   //declare event handler for printing in constructor
   printdoc1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printdoc1_PrintPage);
}

public void GetPrintArea(Panel pnl)
{            
   MemoryImage = new Bitmap(pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
   pnl.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, new Rectangle(0,0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height));
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  if (MemoryImage != null)
  {
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, 0,0);
      base.OnPaint(e);                
  }
}

public void printdoc1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   Rectangle pagearea = e.PageBounds;
   e.Graphics.RotateTransform(-90);
   yPrintCoordinate = ((CentimeterToPixel(Convert.ToDouble(txtWidth.Text))) - (2 * (CentimeterToPixel(Convert.ToDouble(txtWidth.Text))))) - 32;
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, yPrintCoordinate, 0);
}

public void Print(Panel pnl)
{        
   pannel = pnl;
   GetPrintArea(pnl);
   printdoc1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("Cheque Size", CentimeterToPixel(Convert.ToDouble(heightSize)), (CentimeterToPixel(Convert.ToDouble(widthSize))));
   previewdlg.Document = printdoc1;
   previewdlg.ShowDialog();
}

int CentimeterToPixel(double Centimeter)
{
   double pixel = -1;
   using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
   {
    pixel = Centimeter * g.DpiY / 2.54d;
   }
   return (int)pixel;
}

private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   Print(panel1);
}
```